# Array initialization with ternary operator in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, conditional-operator

Why will Java let me initialize an array like this:
int[] anotherArray = {1,2,3,4,5};

But won't accept this:
int[] anArray = (arr.length > 0) ? {1,2,3,4,5}: {};

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4h3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code work, do the following instead:

```
int[] anArray = (arr.length > 0) ? new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}: new int[]{};
```

To understand why the original code didn't work, we need to understand two things: 1) the ternary operator, and 2) the ways to initialize an array.

**1. The ternary operator (?:)**

The ...`?`...`:`... expression is called the ternary operator (not lambda). It is simply a shorthand for an if-else statement. You can find out more about the ternary operator in the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

> Another conditional operator is ?:, which can be thought of as
> shorthand for an if-then-else statement

**2. Ways to initialize arrays in Java**

`int[] anArray = {1,2,3,4,5}` (without `new`) is a shorthand for instantiating an array, and can only be used when initializing the array *during* declaration. When an array is instantiated outside of declaration, the `new` operator must be used ("new int[]{...}"). For example:

```
int[] b = new int[] {1, 2, 3} // ok
int[] c = {1, 2, 3} // ok

int[] arr;
arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3} // ok
arr = {1, 2, 3} // compilation error
```

More about array creation in the section "Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array" in the Oracle tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

**Why the original code didn't work**

Putting the above pieces of information together, 1) `?:` is simply another way of writing an if-else statement, and 2) when instantiating an array outside of declaration the `new` operator is required. Your original statement is equivalent to the following:

```
int[] anArray;
if (arr.length > 0) {
    anArray = {1,2,3,4,5} // compilation error
} else {
    anArray = {}; // compilation error
}
```

To fix the compilation error, the `new` operator should be used:

```
int[] anArray;
if (arr.length > 0) {
    anArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5} // ok
} else {
    anArray = new int[]{}; // ok
}
```

Which then simplifies to:

```
int[] anArray = (arr.length > 0) ? new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}: new int[]{};
```

Comment: Thank you. That was extremely helpful.

Comment: Glad to help, you're most welcome.